# Fadein loop for class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop through each element of a class in javascript and display it after pausing a certain amount of seconds. I have the logic down, but because jQuery is calling the class, and not the unique instance of `this`, it displays everything all at once:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function ($) {
    $( ".fadein" ).hide();

    $( ".fadein" ).each(function (index) {
      $( "." + this.className ).delay(index * 800).fadeIn( "slow" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The each loop is already designed to hand you the elements one at a time.  The target element is passed as 'this', so just fadeIn the current element in your 'loop' instead of fetching all of them each time.

```
// Replace this
$( "." + this.className ).delay(index * 800).fadeIn( "slow" );
// with this
$( this ).delay(index * 800).fadeIn( "slow" );

// result:
$( ".fadein" ).each(function (index) {
    $( this ).delay(index * 800).fadeIn( "slow" );
});
```

Comment: Perfect. I was calling `this.delay...` and it didn't work. Thank you

Comment: @MikeEdwards yes. didnt notice. +1